# Unsolvable first order nonlinear differential equation? $\frac{dx(t)}{dt} + \sin(x(t)) = \sin(\omega t)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I do want to solve the following differential equation analytically:
$$\frac{dx(t)}{dt} + \sin(x(t)) = \sin(\omega t)$$
I tried several methods to solve this equation, unfortunately without any success. In the last week, I have read a lot of papers related to that kind of prototype and have looked into all the books that deal with first order differential equations. It still seems to be impossible. Neither Wolfram-alpha, nor Matlab's symbolic toolbox can give me a solution for it. Because of that, I am wondering if there is actually a solution for that kind of differential equation?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: No CAS being able to solve is a very good sign that you can't neither. Due to the non-linearity (sine), I doubt that there is a closed-form expression. For small angles, use $\sin x\approx x$.

Comment: What about assumptions? Could that help you to find a solution? Actually I can not believe that such an equation is not solvable.

Comment: It's very likely that there are no closed-form solutions to this differential equation.  Most differential equations are like that.  Of course there **are** solutions.  You can solve the differential equation numerically, or find arbitrarily many terms of a series.

Comment: Thanks. However, I cannot use the small-angle approximation, because I do need that term in order to describe a certain physical phenomena. Any more guesses?

Comment: The problem is the following: You do not have saturation nor harmonics without the sinus term. If you excite with a sinusoid at high amplitude the response would contain only the fundamental frequency without the term.

Comment: Using numerics does not give you much insight into the actual physics...

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Do you know how you could find arbitrarily many terms of a series for that kind of differential equation?

Comment: E.g. in Maple: dsolve({D(y)(t) + sin(y(t)) = sin(w*t), y(0)=y0}, y(t), series, order=20);

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Of course solutions **do exist**, we might just be unable to find closed form representations for them. This doesn't mean we can't compute them numerically: here are some IVP trajectories with $\omega=1$
[image]

You can plot just a fundamental patch $t\in[0,2\pi]$, $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$ thanks to the periodicity (I've highlighted in red the stable periodic solution and in blue the unstable periodic solution):
[image]

Alternative visualization:
[image]

**Edit.** Code for the plots, in Mathematica:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{
    x'[t] + Sin[x[t]] == Sin[t],
    x[0] == x0},
   x, {t, 0, 4 \[Pi]}, {{x0, -3 \[Pi], 3 \[Pi]}}];
Plot[Evaluate@Table[
   x[x0][t] /. sol, {x0, -3 \[Pi], 2.5 \[Pi], .25}], {t, 0, 3.5 \[Pi]}]

per = NDSolve[{
    x'[t] + Sin[x[t]] == Sin[t],
    x[0] == x[2 \[Pi]]},
   x, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}];
Show[StreamPlot[{1, Sin[t] - Sin[x]}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}],
 Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. per], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

Comment: Thanks! What exactly does the fundamental patch tell me? It does not seem to be just another representation of the solution x(t) with respect to t.

Comment: Well, you know that the entire plane is filled with this repeating pattern, so this picture gives a pretty complete idea of the behavior of the solutions.

Comment: I've now added a plot of the periodic solution overlaid on top of the stream plot. From the first picture you can see that this periodic solutions are attractive. You might be interested in studying this phenomenon, related to the stability of the system

Comment: A bit harder to see in that plot, but there's also another (unstable) periodic solution with $y(0) \approx 2.604965594$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Updated to the plot, thanks

Comment: $\displaystyle +1$. Thanks. For your nice answer and the ${\displaystyle\tt Mathematica}$ lecture. Nice job.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, this differential equation can be "solved analytically", albeit in terms of non elementary functions.

First we have the equation

$$\frac{dx(t)}{dt} + \sin(x(t)) = \sin(\omega t)$$

which i will rewrite as

$$\frac{dx}{dt} + \sin(x) = \sin(\omega t)$$

(to make it easier type)

now substitute
$$x= -\frac{\cos(\omega t)}{\omega} + u$$

therefore $$\frac{dx}{dt}= \sin(\omega t) + \frac{du}{dt}$$

after rearranging the equation becomes
$$\frac{du}{dt} + \sin\left(-\frac{\cos(\omega t)}{\omega} + u\right) =0$$

which can be rewritten as
$$\frac{du}{dt} = \sin\left(\frac{\cos(\omega t)}{\omega} - u\right)$$

now using the identity $\sin(\theta) = \frac {e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}{2i}$

our equation can be rewritten as
$$\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{e^{i\left(\frac{\cos(\omega t)}{\omega} - u\right)}-e^{i\left(\frac{-\cos(\omega t)}{\omega} + u\right)}}{2i}$$

now we rearrange the terms to arrive at
$$2i\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{e^{i\left(\frac{\cos(\omega t)}{\omega}\right)}}{e^{iu}}- \frac {e^{iu}} {e^{i\left(\frac{\cos(\omega t)}{\omega}\right)}}$$

now substitute $e^{iu} = v$

therefore $$ \frac{dv}{dt}=iv \frac{du}{dt}$$

Also $$ \frac{2}{v} \frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{e^{i\left(\frac{\cos(\omega t)}{\omega}\right)}}{v}- \frac {v} {e^{i\left(\frac{\cos(\omega t)}{\omega}\right)}}$$

Now we can use variable separation method by grouping the terms having $v$

in the denominator and then rearrange the equation as

$$ \frac{1}{v^2} \frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{1}{{e^{i\left(\frac{\cos(\omega t)}{\omega}\right)}}{\left(e^{i\left(\frac{\cos(\omega t)}{\omega}\right)}-2\right)}}$$

for now we shall focus on the RHS (right hand side)
$$ RHS = \frac{-1}{2{e^{i\left(\frac{\cos(\omega t)}{\omega}\right)}}} + \frac{1}{2{\left(e^{i\left(\frac{\cos(\omega t)}{\omega}\right)}-2\right)}} $$

(By method of partial fractions)

Now to solve this ode we must integrate this equation with respect to t

NOTE: These integrals are non elementary

To avoid clutter i will integrate each term of the RHS separately
let $$I_1 =\frac{-1}{2} \int e^{-i\left(\frac{\cos(\omega t)}{\omega}\right)}dt$$

Substitute $p=-i\left(\frac{\cos(\omega t)}{\omega}\right)$

Also $dp=i \sin(\omega t)dt=i(1+(w^2p^2))^{\frac{1}{2}}dt $

Thus
$$I_1 =\frac{-1}{2} \int \frac{e^{p}}{i(1+(w^2p^2))^{\frac{1}{2}}}dp$$

Taylor series expansion of$$ \frac{1}{(1+(w^2p^2))^{\frac{1}{2}}}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2n-1)!!\,(-1)^n (w)^{2n} p^{2n}}{(2^n) (n!)}$$

Now substitute this in the integral, separate the constants and interchange the

integral and summation
$$I_1 =\frac{i}{2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2n-1)!!\,(-1)^n (w)^{2n} \int{e^p p^{2n}}}{(2^n) (n!)}dp$$

Finally $$I_1 =\frac{i}{2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2n-1)!!\,(-1)^n (w)^{2n}\: \Gamma(2n+1,-p)}{(2^n) (n!)}$$

Where $\Gamma$ is the incomplete gamma function and $p=-i\left(\frac{\cos(\omega t)}{\omega}\right)$

Now let $$I_2 =\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{\left(e^{i\left(\frac{\cos(\omega t)}{\omega}\right)}-2\right)}dt$$

Substitute $z=e^{i\left(\frac{\cos(\omega t)}{\omega}\right)}$ in the expansion of $\frac{1}{z-2}$

To obtain $$\frac{1}{e^{i\left(\frac{\cos(\omega t)}{\omega}\right)}-2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{1+n}\:e^{ni\left(\frac{\cos(\omega t)}{\omega}\right)}$$

Now substitute the summation in the integral and separate its first term
$$I_2 =\frac{-1}{4} \int {\left(1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}\:e^{ni\left(\frac{\cos(\omega t)}{\omega}\right)}\right)}dt$$

Interchange the summation and integral sign and simplify to obtain
$$I_2 =\frac{-1}{4} t + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}\:\int e^{ni\left(\frac{\cos(\omega t)}{\omega}\right)}dt$$

Now let $I_3=\int e^{ni\left(\frac{\cos(\omega t)}{\omega}\right)}dt$

Similar to how $I_1$ was 'solved', $I_3$ can be 'solved'
by substituting
$$Q_n=ni\left(\frac{\cos(\omega t)}{\omega}\right)$$

So $I_2$ will evaluate to a double summation

The LHS will evaluate to a function of x

(The final solution is too long to type in neatly)